# Trying to understand why my if else statement does not work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, if-statement

I am quite sure there are better ways of implementing what I am trying to do, and I am just trying different avenues to see what works best for me... So I have a UISegmentedController with 4 segments. I gave each a title in interface Builder and what I am trying to do is when they press a certain segment it will play the corresponding video. I am using a webview because... well that is what i know... so far... here is my code:

```
-(IBAction) getVideo: (id) sender
{
 NSURL *videoURl;
 NSString *videoURLString;
 NSString *video;

 video = [videoChoice titleForSegmentAtIndex:
   videoChoice.selectedSegmentIndex];

 if (video = @"Shimmy") {
  videoURLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
        @"http://www.andalee.com/iPhoneVideos/mov.MOV"];
 } else if (video = @"Camel") {
  videoURLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
        @"http://www.andalee.com"];
 } else {
  videoURLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
        @"http://www.yahoo.com"];
 }

 videoURl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: videoURLString];
 [videoView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: videoURl]];

 [videoURl release];
 [videoURLString release];
}
```

So when I use this (video = @"Shimmy") it goes straight to the video but the same for every segment... now if I change it to (video == @"Shimmy") it goes straight to the else and nothing... else. By the way the links right now are irrelevant just trying to understand the mechanics.

Comment: Make sure you have `-Wall` set as an "other warning flag" and you enable the "Run static analyser" build option.  That way, you'll get a warning when you accidentally use `=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Objective-C the test `video == @"Shimmy"` compares 2 string objects, while `video = @"Shimmy"` is an assignment. What you want is:

```
if ([video isEqualToString:@"Shimmy"])
```

good luck

P.S. and if we're talking about better practices, you can allocate an NSString, using one of convenience methods and it will be autoreleased later. Like instead of

```
videoURLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"http://www.yahoo.com"];
```

you can use

```
videoURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.yahoo.com"];
```

of cause don't call release in the end.

Answer (score 6):

When you use one equal sign you're doing an assignment.  So:

```
if (video = @"Shimmy")
```

This is testing to see if you were able to successfully change `video` to point to the string `@"Shimmy"`.

Using two equal signs tests for explicit equality.  So:

```
if (video == @"Shimmy")
```

This tests to see if video is equal and identical to `@"Shimmy"`.  Note that the following will be **false**:

```
if ([NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Shimmy"] == @"Shimmy")
```

Because the first string is not the same string as the second string.  They may have the same content, but they're not the same object.

What you're looking for is:

```
if ([video isEqual:@"Shimmy"])
```

This tests content equality.

Comment: Dave i think that if(video == @"Shimmy") will check the memory address of both the objects. And it will return true only if both are on the same memory address. thats y it will return false

Comment: @robin right.  In other words, they're not identical.  They're not the same object.

Comment: When you know both sides of an equality relation are NSStrings, you can use `-isEqualToString:` which is a little bit faster than `-isEqual:`

Answer (score 1):

With video = @"Shimmy" you make an assignment to the variable video. The result of this assignment is @"Shimmy" which is evaluated as not false, so ghe if condition is true and the statement executed.

With == you make a pointer value comparision. This will only be trie in rare cases -exactly when the value has a pointer to exactly the same string. This will never be true if you compare with a ststic @"string".

you need to use a function to compare strings, e.g.

if ([value isEqualToString:@"Shimmy"]) {...}

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont know anything about Objective C , but i guess as per other programming languages ,
= is just plain assignment and would return true and hence the if loop always evluates,
and == checks for the contents.

Try reading up [here](http://www.jchq.net/certkey/0502certkey.htm) the difference between equals and == in Objective C

Comment: Actually when you use = in if statement like this if(t = 47) then the expression inside if will return 47 which is true but if you use t = 0 than it will return 0 value which is false so dont get confuse. Try it

Comment: Ahhh yes , any non-zero value evaluates to true... Thanks Robin for pointing that !!! :)